# awk failed to concatenate row with a variable ($PWD)

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file with list of directories:

```
$ cat dirs.txt
/some/path
/other/path
/some/another/one
```

Current directory is `/home/loom`

```
$ echo $PWD
/home/loom
```

I would like to add `$PWD` to each row of `dirs.txt` like the following:

```
/home/loom/some/path
/home/loom/other/path
/home/loom/some/another/one
```

I unsuccessfully tried the command:

```
$ cat dirs.txt | awk '{print $PWD$1}'
/some/path/some/path
/other/path/other/path
/some/another/one/some/another/one
```

It just doubled each row. What command solves my problem?

---

I mean parametric answer, not `cat dirs.txt | awk '{print "/home/loom" $1}'`

Answer (score 3):

`PWD` is a shell variable and therefore won't expand inside the single quotes used by awk.

```
awk -v pwd="$PWD" '{print pwd$1}' dirs.txt
```

This will set the `pwd` `awk` variable to the value of the `PWD` shell variable and then print column 1 of each line in `dirs.txt` with that value prepended to the beginning.

Using GNU awk you can use the `-i inplace` option to overwrite your file with the output, otherwise you will have to redirect it to a new file and overwrite the old file with that if desired.

Comment: +1.  BTW, if the variable has been exported, you can use the awk built-in array `ENVIRON`.   e.g.  `awk '{print ENVIRON["PWD"]$1}' dirs.txt`.   Using `-v` makes for more readable code, IMO.   Also watch out for filenames containing the `=` character: awk will interpret them as variable assignments similar to `-v` (but this happens **after** any BEGIN block).   e.g. `echo | awk '{print foo}' foo=bar`

Comment: The functional difference between using `-v` and `ENVIRON` is that the former will expand escape sequences (so `foo\tbar` will become `foo<tab>bar`) while the latter won't. You can use ENVIRON for non-exported variables too, you just need to set the shell variable to itself on the awk command line, e.g. `shellvar="$shellvar" awk 'BEGIN { awkvar=ENVIRON["shellvar"]...`. The issue about `=` (or `-`) in file names only applies to arguments, not to input.

Answer (score 1):

There're of course more ways to do so, so since you're asking for any command that solves your problem, another way could be this:

```
while read -r line; do echo "${PWD}${line}"; done < "dirs"
```

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Thank you, learnt a few things.